# VB.NET+ WPF + usercontrol transition effect, please?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, slide

I really need help for anyone can give me example in VB.NET + WPF + Fluidkit
I am trying to create application which can switch views with animation slide. I know Fluidkit has example but in C#, and i tried to convert C# source to VB.NET but with too many errors.

Can someone give me example how to create animation slide between views in VB.NET ? or at least working example VB.NET + Fluidkit for WPF

Thank you in advance

UPDATE :
dear Master,

after searching and searching on internet, i almost figure this out. By some references from expert I manage to design 'MDI' and show the child form in mainform. What i want is show animation when child form shown on mainform (slide transition effect).
On my project I have :
1. mainwindow.xaml
2. page1.xaml (usercontrol)

the XAML for mainwindow as follow :

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" Margin="0,0,-8,0">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="TransformImage">
                <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="page1"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"
        By="100" Duration="0:0:3">
                </DoubleAnimation>
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnClick">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource TransformImage}"/>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <StackPanel x:Name="Stk" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="281" Margin="-1,40,0,-283" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="519"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnClick" Content=" Show Child" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,6" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to show page1.xaml using slide transition effect, but I got error when I pressed BtnClick where page1.xaml not exist within mainform.xaml

Please help me.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally i manage to make transition effect on my project by applying MahApps.Metro TransitioningContentControl. Here what I did on XAML :

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                      xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
                      Title="MainWindow" 
                      Height="350" 
                      Width="525">

    <Grid Margin="0,40,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="1,-37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="379">
            <Button x:Name="btnClick" Content="Show" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="14" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="71"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Controls:TransitioningContentControl x:Name="transitioning" Transition="Left"   Margin="0,0,0,0" />

    </Grid>
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

And the code behind as follow

```
Imports MahApps.Metro.Controls
Partial Public Class MainWindow

    Private Sub btnClick_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnClick.Click
        Dim pageww As New page1
        transitioning.Content = pageww
    End Sub
End Class
```

Maybe can be useful for anyone like to apply transition effect on project
N.B : still I want to find out the hard way by using storyboard and trigger